# How do torrent clients like Utorrent work behind the scenes?

Tags: connection, bittorrent, utorrent

I am looking to write my own small scale torrent client, similar to Utorrent. However I am unsure of how to even begin to establish a connection to the different seeders. Once I have a torrent file containing all of the data how can I decode it and interpret it?

What is the protocol to establish a connection to the trackers? Assuming my knowledge and terminology is correct once I connect to the trackers found within the torrent file, I will then receive a list of some sort containing the seeders IP and Ports. Then can I connect and begin to download pieces of the file from the seeders.

Also I know that Utorrent lists current seeders IP and I think their port as well. Once I know a seeders IP and port is it possible to manually establish a connection and start downloading the file pieces? Or is there a handshake or layer of security that prevents that?

Comment: I think you should ask this on stackoveflow.

Comment: Sounds like you have some research to do, and some ideas on where to look. On its own this question is too broad to be appropriately answered on SU/SO.

Comment: Even on SO, this would be rather broad.  Looking at a Torrent spec or the source code for an existing open source client would be a better starting point.

Comment: Although I feel the basis of these questions reveals you're out of your depth and that there isn't much you can provide to the torrent scene, I will recommend you find an open-source torrent client and review the code they use. One is Deluge: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Download

Comment: Well stackoverflow is directed for programming specific questions. This question isn't looking for code but rather knowledge on how torrent clients work behind the scenes.

Comment: To be honest, your best bet is to find an open source project and browse the code to actually see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bittorrent protocol is detailed [here](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html).  You can also study the source code of an open-source Bittorrent application such as Transmission.

> What is the protocol to establish a connection to the trackers?

HTTP.

> Once I know a seeders IP and port is it possible to manually establish a connection and start downloading the file pieces? Or is there a handshake or layer of security that prevents that?

If the peer hasn't choked you due to you being stingy or unreliable.  There's probably more to it, I haven't read the full spec in a long time.  Read the spec.

As far as access-level security, there is none beyond that choking mechanism, which isn't really a security measure but just a fairness enforcement measure.  I'm not entirely sure how encryption works but it's only to protect the transport and not to serve to identify the peer.  As far as making sure that the pieces peers give out are parts of the torrent, that's what the SHA-1 hashes are for.